# Kruskal-Wallis and Dunn's

Tags: kruskal-wallis-test, dunn-test

I am trying to interpret the results of some experiments I have run, involving showing participants videos of animated synthesised speech.

I ran a mean opinion score test. I made 36 movies in total. 9 each with the following exaggeration factors: 1(A), 1.1(B), 1.2(C), 1.3(D).

11 participants were shown the movies in a randomised order, and asked to score each movie between 1 and 5, based on their opinion of the quality of animation.

The mean opinion scores were: A - 2.41, B - 3.06, C - 3.3, D - 2.99, making C (1.2) the favourite.

A Kruskal-Wallis test (null hypothesis - the samples come from the same distribution) puts the $p$-value at 1.8595e-08, making it extremely unlikely that they come from the same distribution. Therefore we reject the null hypothesis and the test is significant at 0.01 level.

So then I ran Dunn's test to try and ascertain which of the treatments is significantly preferred. Using the Matlab function Dunn, I get the following results, but I don't know what they are telling me.

```
STEPDOWN DUNN TEST FOR NON PARAMETRIC MULTIPLE COMPARISONS

Group     N            Sum of ranks         Mean rank
 1        99             13893.00              140.33
 2        99             20879.50              210.90
 3        99             23569.50              238.08
 4        99             20264.00              204.69

Ties factor: 6882

Test        Q-value        Critical Q         Comment
3 vs 1      6.0084         2.6310             Reject Ho
3 vs 4      2.0525         2.6310             Fail to reject Ho
3 vs 2      No comparison made                Accept Ho
2 vs 1      4.3381         2.6310             Reject Ho
2 vs 4      0.3822         2.6310             Fail to reject Ho
4 vs 1      3.9559         2.6310             Reject Ho

Resuming...
     0     1     1     1
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

```
Friedman's ANOVA Table
    Source  SS  df  MS  Chi-sq  Prob>Chi-sq
    Columns 27.2841 1   27.2841 55.5501 9.1106e-14
    Error   167.2159    395 0.42333     
    Total   194.5   791         
    Test for column effects after row effects are removed
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three points:

1. The null hypothesis of the Kruskal-Wallis **is not** what you have written, but rather *stochastic equality*, H$_{0}\text{: P}\left(X_{i} > X_{j}\right) = 0.5$ for all $i,j \in \{1,\dots,k\}$ for $k$ groups (assuming the CDFs of any two groups do not cross), so you are testing for [stochastic dominance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_dominance). When more stringent assumptions that each treatment has identically shaped distributions, and differences are entirely in location-shift, then you can interpret the null hypothesis as equality of medians, and the test as a test for median difference; and
2. Your data do not sound appropriate to the Kruskal-Wallis test, because you have a *blocked study design* where the same individuals are measured repeatedly. Thus you are looking for a repeated measures test for 'treatment', given your scoring variable, [repeated measures ANOVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeated_measures_design#Repeated_measures_ANOVA) is perhaps not a good candidate. However, the nonparametric [Friedman test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedman_test) may well suit your needs; plus
3. Tests like Kruskal-Wallis and Friedman assume that the data (your scores) are *continuously* measured. There are often 'corrections for ties' in nonparametric tests, but you should make sure that your statistical software *uses* such, and bear in mind that lots of ties (as might happen when there are only five possible scores) may distort your results.

Comment: thanks for you comments. I have tried the matlab friedman function and go the following information.

Comment: p value = 9.1106e-14

Comment: Friedman's ANOVA Table
Source SS df MS Chi-sq Prob>Chi-sq
Columns 27.2841 1 27.2841 55.5501 9.1106e-14
Error 167.2159 395 0.42333  
Total 194.5 791

Comment: The comment forum won't seem to allow me to format this table, so I'll post it in my question at the top!

Comment: So this is telling me there is a difference, but again doesn't tell me which is preferred?

Comment: That's generally the way omnibus tests work, yes. You will need to find an appropriate *post hoc* test to identify which 'treatments' are different from which.

Comment: Actually they are continuously measured, or as continuously measured as is reasonable to talk about on a computer. The test program gave the users a slider to set between 1-5, and the slider measured up to 3 decimal places.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for a post-hoc test? I really know very little about stats and don't really know where to start looking.

Comment: The linked Wikipedia article gives references to folks who have developed *post hoc* tests. I'd start there.

Comment: In the end I settled for ANOVA and Tukey's range test.

Comment: @shaw2thefloor ANOVA does not correctly capture the contracted variance implied by a blocked design (unless you mean repeated measures ANOVA?).